# Is there a name or term for these types of statements that avoid over-generalizations?

Tags: word-choice

In the news, whenever a reporter or commentator talks about police violence, specifically towards minorities, and they imply racist motives behind police brutality, they also tend to add something like this:

*Now of course we don't mean to say that all police are racist or aggressive.*

or like this...

*let's get something straight. Not all cops are bad.*

I used to refer to these statements as **qualifiers** but now I'm thinking that it is incorrect.

Is there another word, term, or word phrase used for these types of statements in discourse that avoid over-generalizing a people, profession, or group? It's unfortunate that journalists or people in general have to say these because unless they do it mean that the speaker is understood to be painting this group with a broad brush.

Comment: how about [*disclaimer*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclaimer)?

Comment: What's most unfortunate is when people make such disclaimers even though what they disclaim is *exactly* what they mean to say.  Used carefully, such a disclaimer can even draw attention to that intended, disclaimed meaning, exactly opposite to the effect it seems on the surface to intend.

Comment: Consider "usual caution".

Answer (score 2):

I believe the common term for this would be a ***[disclaimer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclaimer)***:

> a statement that is meant to prevent an incorrect understanding of something (such as a book, a movie, or an advertisement)
>   <sub>*source: [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclaimer)*</sub>

The person who is speaking is making a claim about someone or something, but specifically "dis-claims" that their statement applies to an entire group:  they make it clear that they are not claiming the broader application.